# Finding variable values passed as parameter and replacing with another variable value in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, environment-variables

I would like to find the variable values in the script like Apples and Bananas and replace the value with Apple for Apples and Banana with Bananas. Basically if the script identifies Apples passed as a parameter, it should change it to Apple and vice versa.

Not looking for Sed or regex.

Two Parameters for fresh_fruits will be Apples, Bananas

Fruits=${fresh_fruits}

Comment: Change *the parameter*, meaning you want to change what `$1` refers to, or are you just setting `foo=$1` and then want to update `$foo`? This question would be greatly helped by having some actual code in it to make what you're looking for explicit.

Comment: And do you just want to trim a trailing `s` whenever one exists, or to match the specific strings `Apples` and `Bananas`?

Comment: ...in either event you should probably look at [the `case` statement](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case), and in the former you should definitely look at [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: Two Parameters for fresh_fruits will be Apples, Bananas

Fruits=${fresh_fruits}

Comment: Please [edit] the question -- that provides more room for a clear description than a comment field is amenable to. See the [mcve] definition in the Help Center for guidance on providing code that illustrates your question effectively.

Comment: `Fruits=${fresh_fruits}` doesn't really tell us anything useful about your question in and of itself. Providing a runnable script with current output and desired output would be a more useful place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updating All Positional Parameters

When you say "passed as parameters", I assume that you're referring to modifying the values of positional arguments.

One way to do this is with an associative array mapping your existing to desired values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# this code requires bash 4.0 -- fail if run with non-bash or older shell
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || [[ $BASH_VERSION = [1-3]* ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: Script requires bash 4.0 or newer" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# here's the important part: map the values we want to replace to the new versions
declare -A parameter_map=(
  [Apples]=Apple
  [Bananas]=Banana
)

# build an args array containing converted versions of our arguments
args=( )
for arg; do
  if [[ ${parameter_map[$arg]+exists} ]]; then
    args+=( "${parameter_map[$arg]}" )
  else
    args+=( "$arg" )
  fi
done

# update the script's arguments based on the above
set -- "${args[@]}"

# for test purposes, print all our arguments
echo "Arguments as follows:"
printf ' - %q\n' "$@"
```

If run as `./yourscript Apples Bananas Pear`, output will be:

```
Arguments as follows:
- Apple
- Banana
- Pear
```

---

#### Updating A Single Variable

If we don't need to update the whole argument list, this gets easier to do in a POSIX-compliant way, *without* a need for arrays (associative or otherwise):

```
#!/bin/sh

var=$1

case $var in
  Apples) var=Apple ;;
  Bananas) var=Banana ;;
esac

echo "New value: $var"
```

Comment: I have a path at the end of the script with parameter for like below home/$fresh_fruits/working

Comment: where can I paste the solution that you gave for this script to execute? Is it before the path or at the begging of the script? Please help

Comment: So what you want to replace is a variable *value*, not a positional parameter? This is much easier, then.

Comment: ...that said, the original code will replace the full argument list (`$1`, `$2`, etc) if put at the beginning of the script.